How to stop message processing? Die or Exit not helps, bet restart MessageHandler
How to stop MessageHandler process? die or exit command restart docker container with this MessageHandler
P.s. I can solve it with nested if  but maybe there are smart solution ?
#[AsMessageHandler]
class SongArtworkCrawlingMessageHandler
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        private readonly LoggerInterface $logger,
        private readonly MessageBusInterface $messageBus,
        #[Autowire('%kernel.project_dir%')]
        private string $projectDir,
    ) {
    }

    public function __invoke(SongArtworkCrawlingMessage $crawlingMessage)
    {
        $urlQuery       = str_replace(' ', '+', $crawlingMessage->getSongTitleAndArtist());
        $urlQuery       = str_replace('_', '+', $urlQuery);
        $url            = 'https://www.radioskonto.lv/search?query='.$urlQuery;

        $browser        = Client::createChromeClient();
        $songArtwork    = new SongArtwork();
        $browser->request('GET', $url);
        sleep(2);

        if ($browser->getCrawler()->filter('.css-0 > a')->count() === 0) {
            $songArtworkNotFound = new SongArtworkNotFound();
            $songArtworkNotFound->setSongArtistTitle($crawlingMessage->getSongTitleAndArtist());
            $songArtworkNotFound->setFailReason('No Data to crawl');
            $songArtworkNotFound->setCreatedAt(new \DateTimeImmutable());
            $this->entityManager->persist($songArtworkNotFound);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            die('No data to crawl - '.$url);   // <<<---- PROBLEM IS HERE
            /// OR
            exit('No data to crawl - '.$url);
        }

// CODE with Crawling and saving process below

}



It's unclear what you want to happen. You want the process "messenger:consume": to die and not to be restarted? And manage that from a handler? And what would you like to happen with messages pending processing when/if the consumer is restarted in the future? Your use case is really not clear.

This looks like a poorly designed solution. You are using messenger to trigger a long-running process, which you keep alive and want to kill. Why not run the long-running process directly (within a CLI command, for example), and simply return when it's done?

To gracefully stop the MessageHandler process without restarting the Docker container, avoid using die or exit since they forcefully terminate the process, potentially causing issues with the Docker container lifecycle. It's better to create custom Exception.
class SongArtworkNotFoundException extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct($message = "No data to crawl", $code = 0, Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }
}

So you can do something like this:
...
if ($browser->getCrawler()->filter('.css-0 > a')->count() === 0) {
    $songArtworkNotFound = new SongArtworkNotFound();
    $songArtworkNotFound->setSongArtistTitle($crawlingMessage->getSongTitleAndArtist());
    $songArtworkNotFound->setFailReason('No Data to crawl');
    $songArtworkNotFound->setCreatedAt(new \DateTimeImmutable());
    $this->entityManager->persist($songArtworkNotFound);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
    
    throw new SongArtworkNotFoundException('No data to crawl - ' . $url);
}
...

